# fatal error in pmpi_gather

Tags: c++, runtime-error, openmpi, mpich

So I have a raytracer I'm writing which compiles just fine, but when I get to the MPI_Gather() function I get this error set.  If I write to files the whole thing finishes fine, but then I can't run it on a distributed computing system.

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Gather: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
PMPI_Gather(856)......:
   MPI_Gather(sbuf=0x8e05468, scount=882000, MPI_BYTE, rbuf=0x8df7628, rcount=882000, MPI_BYTE, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Gather_impl(681).: 
MPIR_Gather(641)......: 
MPIR_Gather_intra(152): 
MPIR_Localcopy(378)...:
   memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x8df7628 src=0x8e05468 len=882000

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
```

I'm not exactly sure what this error means, so it's hard to get around it.

Here is the source for the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  clock_t total_time = clock(), otime;
  init_MPI(argc, argv);   //Initialize OpenMPI
  glutInit(&argc,argv);

  get_params(argc, argv);   //Get parameters from command line
  if (buildScene(scene, cam) == -1) MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc); exit(1);
  samples = samples > 0 ? whitted ? 1 : samples : 1;
  if (numprocs == 1) {
    scn = new RGBApixmap(h,w);
    raytrace(h,scn);
    if (smult > 1) *scn = scaleImage(scn,smult);
  } else {
    int rows = h / numprocs;
    subscn = new RGBApixmap(rows,w);
    raytrace(rows, subscn);
    if (smult > 1) *subscn = scaleImage(subscn,smult);

    if (pid == MASTER) scn = new RGBApixmap(h/smult,w/smult);
    MPI_Gather(subscn,rows/smult*w,MPI_BYTE,scn,rows/smult*w,MPI_BYTE,MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  if (pid == MASTER) {
    initGlut(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I've fixed the problem and posted updated code below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  clock_t total_time = clock(), otime;
  init_MPI(argc, argv);
  glutInit(&argc,argv);    
  bool OK = get_params(argc, argv);
  if (buildScene(scene, cam) == -1) { MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc); exit(1); }
  samples = samples > 0 ? whitted ? 1 : samples : 1;
  int rows = h / numprocs;
  subscn = new RGBApixmap(rows,w);
  raytrace(rows, subscn);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);          /* Synchronize all processes */   
  if (smult > 1) *subscn = scaleImage(subscn,smult); 
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);          /* Synchronize all processes */

  int nElts = subscn->getWidth()*subscn->getHeight();
  RGBA *subscnpix, *scnpix;
  subscnpix = subscn->getPixs();
  scnpix = (RGBA*)malloc(sizeof(RGBA)*((w/smult)*(h/smult)));

  MPI_Datatype pixel;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(4,MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR,&pixel);
  MPI_Type_commit(&pixel);

  MPI_Gather(subscnpix,nElts,pixel,scnpix,nElts,pixel,MASTER,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  scn = new RGBApixmap(h/smult,w/smult,scnpix);

  MPI_Type_free(&pixel);

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);          /* Synchonize all processes */
  if (pid == MASTER) {
    initGlut(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The three calls to `MPI_Barrier` are unnecessary. Your processes only exchange data in the `MPI_Gather` call and this one is collective, i.e. it would wait for all processes to check in before completion at the root. Also, do not use `clock()` as this is highly unportable and it doesn't measure wall clock time (on Unix it measures CPU time that is different from what it measures on Windows). Use `MPI_Wtime()` instead.

Comment: I know that my calls to `MPI_Barrier` are unnecessary, I had them in there from when I was writing files as a debugging step while I was unable to get MPI_Gather to work. My calls to `clock()` are a legacy from before I rewrote the code to OpenMPI, and I was more worried about getting `MPI_Gather` to work than changing them to `MPI_Wtime()` until now, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your send and receive buffers in the call to `MPI_Gather` in rank `MASTER` overlap which is against the restriction, imposed by the MPI standard. `subscn` is at `0x8e05468` while `scn` is at `0x8df7628`. The memory span from `0x8df7628` to `0x8e05468` is only 56896 bytes and you are trying to write to it 882000 times `numprocs` bytes, which won't work.

This is due to the fact that you divide the number of rows by the scaling factor but still forget to divide the image width `w` by the scaling factor.

```c
MPI_Gather(subscn, rows/smult*w/smult, MPI_BYTE,
           scn, rows/smult*w/smult, MPI_BYTE,
           MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note that if the pixmap is not greyscale, you'd also have to multiply the number of data elements by the number of colour components (possibly counting an alpha channel too) or create a contiguous derived datatype instead.

Comment: I tried making your recommended changes but it's still giving me the same error. How can I create a contiguous derived datatype?

Comment: I suggest that you print the values of `rows`, `w` and `smult` in all ranks and see if the calculations make sense. Is your image coloured or greyscale?

Comment: It's colored, with red, green, blue, and alpha values.

Comment: I looked up how to make a derived datatype and came up with a workaround for my problem; I've updated my original question with fixed code.  My RGBApixmap class contains an array of pixels, so I think it was trying to pass the array of pixels `rows/smult*w/smult` times, which caused the memory span overlap. Thanks for your help.